# Vertical alignment in Access reports

Tags: ms-access, report

Is there a way to align the output vertically in Access report? Namely the subform that shall be listing some of the details. 
Went through settings - could not find anything related to alignment.

Example:

[image]

I need the section with listing of offer details to be always vertically aligned (in the middle of the page). If I can align everything (including the page heading) that would also work.

Comment: Pls provide example as to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Adarsh - added the example in description.